# i3-Gaps | Not working after install

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, i3-wm

I recently installed i3-gaps on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Previously, I had been running i3. Now, when I try to log in with i3 selected, the screen flashes at me a few times and then I am back to the default login screen. How do I boot into i3-gaps?

I have not changed the display manager and I can still boot into Unity.

Contents of my i3 log file

```
i3: error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-xrm.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated, reboot and try again.

Comment: Restart your computer, if the login dialog appears change to `tty1` via `ctrl+alt+F1`, then backup `~/.xinitrc` if the file exists and create a new one with the content `exec i3 -V >> ~/i3log-$(date +'%F-%k-%M-%S') 2>&1`. Then run `xstart` and edit your question with the content of the "i3log" file.

Comment: I could not find an ~/. xinitrc and xstart results in a command not found error.

Comment: My mistake I mean `startx`. You could not find the file `~/.xinitrc` or does this file not exists. If the file not exists, create a new one like I said in the comment above.

Comment: edit posted with the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not installed [libxcb-xrm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libxcb-xrm-dev) which is built from the source package `xcb-util-xrm`. In Ubuntu 16.4 you have to install [xcb-util-xrm](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/4owfz8/problem_installing_i3gaps_in_ubuntu_1604/?st=ix8e167u&sh=5d76a2b3) from [source](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Compiling-&-Installing).

```
cd /path/where/you/want/the/repository

# clone the repository
git clone https://www.github.com/Airblader/i3 i3-gaps
cd i3-gaps

# compile & install
autoreconf --force --install
rm -rf build/
mkdir -p build && cd build/

../configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I recompiled everything and now I can boot just fine. Thanks